# segfault when setting character of malloced pointer-to-pointer string

Tags: c, string, pointers, segmentation-fault, pointer-to-pointer

In a bigger project i have been working on, i got an `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`, so i managed to reproduce the problem like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char **x = malloc(10 * 10);
    x[0][0] = 'a';

    printf("%s\n", x[0]);

    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

For some reason, (i don't know why) i get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` when i  set a character in a pointer-to-pointer string (that is `malloc`ed)

Since the pointer is allocated on the heap, shouldn't i be able to change the array elements?

So i tried to initalize the array using `memset` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char **x = malloc(10 * 10);
    memset(x[0], 0x00, 10);
    x[0][0] = 'a';

    printf("%s", x[0]);

    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Maybe i need to use `strcpy`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char **x = malloc(10 * 10);
    strcpy(x[0], "Hi");

    printf("%s", x[0]);

    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
`Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Okay maybe pointer-to-pointer just does not work even if it is on the heap.

What if it is a normal string?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *x = malloc(10);
    x[0] = 'a';

    printf("%s\n", x);

    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**
`a`

So why does a normal pointer work??

Maybe the internet will help.

*Nevermind* after i got bored before finding a *single* solution on the internet.

Can *someone* find a solution?
Im not a genius at how `C` works so do forgive me if said something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this line

```c
char **x = malloc(10 * 10);
```

you are allocating an uninitialized array of `char*`.

`x[0][0]` is dereferencing an uninitialized element `x[0]` of the array, so this will result in Segmentation Fault.

You should allocate some buffer and assign that to the array before copying strings.

Also don't forget to add terminating null-character to use the data as strings.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char **x = malloc(sizeof(*x) * 10);
    x[0] = malloc(10); /* allocate buffer and assign */
    x[0][0] = 'a';
    x[0][1] = '\0'; /* add terminating null-character */

    printf("%s\n", x[0]);

    free(x[0]);
    free(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thanks alot! I did not know that the element dereferenced has to exist first!